# Text rotation not properly working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, symbology

I am trying to create layouts in QGIS for numerous projects, but the raw data is a DXF file with  lots of texts that have fixed rotation angles. If I open the file in a CAD program it looks like this:
[image: text in CAD program]

After converting the data into a Shape-File with the rotation as attributes, this is the result I get in QGIS:

[image: text in QGIS]

It appears, that QGIS does not want the texts to be upside down and in addition rotates the text in another direction as the CAD program. I did not find any solutions on how to fix this issue. Does anyone have any ideas on a solution for that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow upside-down labels using this setting

[image]

And the rotation issue may be because because you are using degrees and it is expecting radians (or vice versa)

[image]

Comment: The upside-down labels helped, don't know how I didn't find that before. But the rotations issue still remains and I think I found the reason for it. QGIS rotation values only go up to 180 degrees, then becoming negative values to -180 degress while CAD uses 360 degrees.

Comment: Good find. You can fix that by creating an expression for the rotation, something like: `case when "rotation" < 0 then "rotation" + 360 else "rotation" end` (where `rotation` is the name of the field containing the angle).

Comment: After trying for 2 hours I found the solution. For some reason the rotation of the labeling is clockwise while the rotation in CAD and other layers in QGIS is counterclockwise. In the end the solution is rather simple by just adding a minus in the expression: -"rotation"